# FastAPI application throws ValueError when installing Openpyxl

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm

I wanted to use Openpyxl to manipulate Excel files in my FastAPI Application. I installed Openpyxl then my application just throws ValueError. I didn't import the module or anything, just installing it breaks my application.

The following is the error.

```
api_1  | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
api_1  | INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using statreload
api_1  | Process SpawnProcess-1:
api_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
api_1  |     self.run()
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
api_1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 61, in subprocess_started
api_1  |     target(sockets=sockets)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 49, in run
api_1  |     loop.run_until_complete(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
api_1  |     return future.result()
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 56, in serve
api_1  |     config.load()
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 308, in load
api_1  |     self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 20, in import_from_string
api_1  |     module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
api_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
api_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
api_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
api_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
api_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
api_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
api_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
api_1  |   File "./app/main.py", line 10, in <module>
api_1  |     from .users.main import setup_auth
api_1  |   File "./app/users/main.py", line 3, in <module>
api_1  |     from .routers import setup_auth_routers
api_1  |   File "./app/users/routers.py", line 10, in <module>
api_1  |     from .schemas import User_Pydantic, UserLoginIn, UserRegisterIn
api_1  |   File "./app/users/schemas.py", line 46, in <module>
api_1  |     User_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name='User')
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tortoise/contrib/pydantic/creator.py", line 353, in pydantic_model_creator
api_1  |     model = get_submodel(fdesc["python_type"])
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tortoise/contrib/pydantic/creator.py", line 304, in get_submodel
api_1  |     pmodel = _pydantic_recursion_protector(
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tortoise/contrib/pydantic/creator.py", line 105, in _pydantic_recursion_protector
api_1  |     return pydantic_model_creator(
api_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tortoise/contrib/pydantic/creator.py", line 405, in pydantic_model_creator
api_1  |     model = cast(Type[PydanticModel], type(_name, (PydanticModel,), properties))
api_1  |   File "pydantic/main.py", line 287, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
api_1  |   File "pydantic/fields.py", line 384, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
api_1  |   File "pydantic/fields.py", line 369, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._get_field_info
api_1  |   File "pydantic/fields.py", line 158, in pydantic.fields.FieldInfo._validate
api_1  | ValueError: cannot specify both default and default_factory
```

From the error it seems like a Pydantic error, but I just can't fix it. Here are the models that it seems to be throwing the error.

`app/resources/core_model.py`

```py
class CoreModel(Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)
    timestamp = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = fields.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    class PydanticMeta:
        exclude = ('user', 'user_id', 'timestamp', 'updated', 'is_active',)
```

`app/users/models.py`

```py
from tortoise import fields
from passlib.hash import bcrypt

from app.resources.core_model import CoreModel


class User(CoreModel):
    username = fields.CharField(50, unique=True)
    email = fields.CharField(60, unique=True)
    password_hash = fields.CharField(128)

    class PydanticMeta(CoreModel.PydanticMeta):
        exclude = (*CoreModel.PydanticMeta.exclude, 'password_hash', )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return bcrypt.verify(password, self.password_hash)
```

`app/users/schemas.py`

```py
import re
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import HTTPException, status
from tortoise.contrib.pydantic import pydantic_model_creator
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from app.resources.constants import EMAIL_REGEX, PASSWORD_REGEX

from .models import User


class UserBaseIn(BaseModel):
    email: str
    password: str

    @validator('email')
    def email_validator(cls, value):
        if not value:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                                detail='Email cannot be empty')
        if not re.match(EMAIL_REGEX, value):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                                detail="Invalid email address.")
        return value

    @validator('password')
    def password_validator(cls, value):
        if not value:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                                detail='Password cannot be empty')
        if not re.match(PASSWORD_REGEX, value):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                                detail="Invalid password.")
        return value


class UserRegisterIn(UserBaseIn):
    username: Optional[str] = None
    pass


class UserLoginIn(UserBaseIn):
    pass


User_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name='User')
UserIn_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name='UserIn', exclude_readonly=True)
```

And the fact that my application breaks soon as installing Openpyxl makes me think it's not really a pydantic problem.

#### Environment

Docker - 20.10.2
Python - 3.9.2
FastAPI - 0.63.0
Openpyxl - 3.0.6
Tortoise ORM - 0.16.21

Any suggestions will help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code provided does not include the relevant section in fields.py.

Comment: @CharlieClark
Thank you for your comment!  
I must be honest I am quite confused. I can see that you are referring to pydantic/fields.py, but I'm not really sure what is missing and why it causes the application to break by just installing Openpyxl.  
May I ask you to be more specific on what could be the issue?

Comment: I know nothing about PyDantic but there is nothing in the code provided that is related to openpyxl. The exception tells you where the problem is and what it is and seems to be related to the validate method for the user. Time for some patient debugging to find what is probably just a simple error.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried debugging this a bit. Based on the traceback I simplified the code and  was able to reproduce the exception.

```
from tortoise import fields
from tortoise.models import Model
from passlib.hash import bcrypt


class CoreModel(Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)
    timestamp = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = fields.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    class PydanticMeta:
        exclude = ('user', 'user_id', 'timestamp', 'updated', 'is_active',)


class User(CoreModel):
    username = fields.CharField(50, unique=True)
    email = fields.CharField(60, unique=True)
    password_hash = fields.CharField(128)

    class PydanticMeta(CoreModel.PydanticMeta):
        exclude = (*CoreModel.PydanticMeta.exclude, 'password_hash', )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return bcrypt.verify(password, self.password_hash)
        

from tortoise.contrib.pydantic import pydantic_model_creator

User_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name='User')
```

Knowing nothing about the underlying library I just looked at anything that might execute and it looks like PyDanticMeta.exclude maps the fieldnames somewhere but two of the fields have different names than in the tuple: `user` and `user_id`. The problem seems to be with the `user_id`; `id` is possible. At a guess I think this is related to some magic in the ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same error but, This isn't pydantic or fastapi errror

its just `tortoise-orm` error

replace `fields.UUIDField` with `fields.IntField` and see if this works